# Why is my JWT only verifying with the private key and not the public key?

Tags: jwt, rsa, sha256

So I have a very strange issue currently where I can generate tokens perfectly fine and send them out to my API client (currently using Insomnia for testing) however on the server the tokens only seem to validate when doing so against the *private* key and not the *public* key. From my research I understand that verifying against the private key, apart from not being the best idea, shouldn't actually be possible!

For context my server is running PHP and I'm using Lcobucci's JWT library

```bash
openssl genrsa -out ./keys/private.key 2048
openssl rsa -in ./keys/private.key -pubout -out ./keys/public.key
```

```php
use Lcobucci\JWT\Token\Builder;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Hmac\Sha256;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Encoding\{ChainedFormatter,JoseEncoder};
use Lcobucci\JWT\UnencryptedToken;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Validation\Validator as JWTValidator;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Validation\Constraint\SignedWith;

$this->private_key = InMemory::file($private_key_path);
$this->public_key = InMemory::file($public_key_path);

// Logging these to the terminal presents them both fine

$token_builder = new Builder(new JoseEncoder(), ChainedFormatter::default());
$algorithm = new Sha256();
$signing_key = $this->private_key;
$now = new \DateTimeImmutable();
$exp = $now->modify('+1 hour');

$access_token = $token_builder
    ->issuedBy('my-system')
    ->permittedFor('my-frontend-system')
    ->identifiedBy(uniqid())
    ->issuedAt($now)
    ->canOnlyBeUsedAfter($now)
    ->expiresAt($exp)
    ->withClaim('user_id', $authentication['user_id'])
    ->withClaim('user_roles', $roles)
    ->getToken($algorithm, $signing_key);
$validator = new JWTValidator();
if (!$validator->validate($access_token, new SignedWith($algorithm, $this->public_key))) {
  throw new AuthenticationException("The generated token was invalid");
}
```

As you'll see above, I've condensed my code so that it attempts to validate the key immediately after generation. And it still throws the exception! Changing `$this->public_key` to `$this->private_key` in the validator then doesn't.

Usually when I type out a question on here and am about to post, I then spot what the issue is or think "hmm, what if I try doing this?" and it works, however that hasn't happened this time so I submit to you, good people of SO: what am I doing wrong?!

Edit in response to a comment: the algorithm in the header is HS256:

```json
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "HS256" // Here's the problem, it should be RS256!
}
```

Comment: What is the actual signature algorithm? (i.e. the "alg" claim in the header of the token)

Comment: @jps it is HS256 and I'll update the question to reflect that

Comment: @jps and now I see the problem!

Comment: yep, that's the point. HS256 is a symmetric algo. You should and probably wanted to use RS256.

Comment: @jps yeah I figured it would kinda just do it automatically, clearly that's not the case!

Answer (score 2):

I'll self-answer this as thanks to jps's answers I now know what I was doing wrong. As is usually the case with these, I've overlooked something really simple and been a bit silly!

Here's the culprit:

```php
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Hmac\Sha256;
```

Which should have in fact been:

```php
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\RSA\Sha256;
```

Needless to say, swapping the symmetrical HMAC for the asymmetrical RSA worked!